# Use Portable library in .NET Core 1.0 RC 2 also target older platforms

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I have a portable class library that targets .net 4.5, .NET Core 1.0, Xamerian and a few others.

I'm trying to load this into an aspnet core 1.0 RC2 project and have it recognize it. When I add it to the dependencies in the project.json they show up, and are in the references section.

However when I go to use them they don't show up in intellisense and throw a compile time error on the line of code that uses them (it compiles fine as long as I don't try and use it.)

How do I get the aspnet core site to use the portable class libraries properly?

**Edit**
By changing to NETSTANDARD11 I was able to get Vs.net to show up everything in intellisense. However on run, even though the items compiled I get an error saying that it can't find the types that are in those classes.

If I convert these two shared class libraries to xproj format then they work in the aspnet core site, but won't work in other .net 4.6 projects because they won't see the dlls that are created.

So how do I create a portable library that works across .NET core and .NET 4.6 that can be loaded in as a project in the solution and added as a solution project reference?

Comment: What exactly does your library target? What Target Framework Moniker do you use?

Comment: Windows 8, .net 4.5, .net core 1.0, xameran Android, xameran iOS

Comment: This is a long standing issue and it is not resolved.  You can read [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45) on the issue for some work-arounds.  Hopefully it will be fixed in RC3.